# Грамматическая основа в предложении: "Прискакал один из моих солдат"

Tags: грамматика, подлежащее

**Прискакал один из моих солдат.**

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти подлежащее.

Answer (score 2):

Подлежащее – ***один из солдат***.

Один из способов выражения подлежащего — (4) конструкция с предлогом ИЗ (выделительное значение):

Любой из них мог это сделать.
**Трое из выпускников** получили золотые медали.
**Самый умный из учеников** не смог решить эту задачу.

([Подлежащее, способы его выражения | gramota.ru](http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part5.htm#311))